# select first object where parent does not have class

Tags: jquery

HTML looks like this

```
<tr class="rowinactive">
<td>
<div class="controllingbuttons">
<a title="Aanpassen" href="/2013-2014/Persoon/Edit/1811?instID=410">
<img width="16" alt="Edit" src="/img/pencil.png">
</a>
...
</td>
</tr>
```

OR

```
<tr> (rowinactive class missing)
<td>
<div class="controllingbuttons">
<a title="Aanpassen" href="/2013-2014/Persoon/Edit/1811?instID=410">
<img width="16" alt="Edit" src="/img/pencil.png">
</a>
...
</td>
</tr>
```

now, I want to count the amount of images in the first div 'controllingbuttons', but its parent TR can not have the 'rowinactive' class.

my code previously (when I didnt care about rowinactive yet)

```
$(".controllingbuttons").first().parent("td").find("img").length
```

I've been trying this, but it doesnt work:

```
$(".controllingbuttons").not($(".controllingbuttons").parents(".rowinactive").find(".controllingbuttons")).first().parent("td").find("img").length
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('tr').not('.rowinactive').find('.controllingbuttons img').length
```

Comment: I think `$('tr').not('.rowinactive').find('.controllingbuttons img').length` will do, or worst case ``$('tr').not('.rowinactive').find('.controllingbuttons').first('img').length``

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes, that's it.

Comment: PS: my original code DID work after all, i had some build issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) along with [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/):

```
$(".controllingbuttons").closest('tr:not(.rowinactive)').length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can tryout this:

```
var imageLen = $(".controllingbuttons").closest('tr:not(.rowinactive)').each(function(){
    return $(this).find('img').length;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

$(".controllingbuttons").parent('tr:not(.rowinactive)').first()

or

$(".controllingbuttons").closest('tr:not(.rowinactive) td:First').length